# Is there a way to use A1 Notation to loop through entire Google Sheet in Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I need to loop through a section of a sheet until the bottom of the sheet.  However, I'm stuck on how to do this and this is my first time using sheets API.  Can I use the A1 notation for this?

I've checked the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation).

Also, I was brought to A1 by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407275/read-spreadsheet-without-knowing-its-range).

However, since A1s are saved as strings, it doesn't help me that much for what I'm doing.

Perhaps I need to have a different function to specifically find the end of the sheet and plug that in.

```
#Retrieve Sheets Data
sheet = client.open("MAC Test").sheet1
data = sheet.get_all_records()
end = 'Class Data!Sheet1'

#Start = 1 for now
start = 1

#Retrieve all rows
for i in range(start, max):
    row = sheet.row_values(i)
    print(row)
```

I can output data just fine in a range, but I need some way to make variables for the start and end of the range.

Comment: It may be possible to do with A1 notation, but please describe more specifically which "section", i.e., range of rows and columns, you need to iterate over?

Comment: @InonPeled So for now, the "range" I was doing was just every single row until the sheet had an empty row (the end of the sheet).  For any A1 notation, would I have to specify the exact cells for each row I traverse?

Answer (score 1):

`gspread.get_all_records` (which I believe you're using) should already give you the number of rows via `len(data)`. If you want the row values (rather than the `data` dictionary you already have) then you just need to iterate over `range(1, len(data)+1)`.

If you need to convert from row and column indices to A1 notation, this isn't available directly from the Google Sheets API. However, [gspread](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which is looks like you're already using, has a [`rowcol_to_a1`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread-utils) utiity.